# Should I disable accounts-daemon?

Tags: fedora, systemd

From `systemctl-analyze blame`, I see that `accounts-daemon.service` is taking a long time.

```
34.042s chronyd.service
28.721s systemd-journal-flush.service
28.269s firewalld.service
21.914s accounts-daemon.service
15.993s lvm2-monitor.service
13.834s dev-sda4.device
11.592s systemd-udev-settle.service
```

I tried searching for what it does but did not get any good information. In fact, [some sources](https://www.linux.com/learn/cleaning-your-linux-startup-process) indicate that this service is a potential risk and **ought to** be disabled.

I just upgraded to Fedora-26 (the only OS in the system), which I am running on my laptop. There are no other users (apart from me and `root`).

Is it safe to disable this service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable this, you probably won't be able to manipulate user accounts from within GNOME programs. There aren't likely to be more dire consequences than that.

On the other hand, it's unlikely that this is *really* slowing down boot. From the `systemctl-analyze blame` documentation:

> Note that the output might be misleading as the initialization of one service might be slow simply because it waits for the initialization of another service to complete.

And, in `accounts-daemon.service`, we find `After=nss-user-lookup.target`. This is a [systemd special target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html), and waiting for that to be ready is counted in the "blame" value you are seeing.

Comment: I use XFCE, and the only GNOME based programs that I use are Evince and Gedit. So, I think it should not be a problem. I realized that the journal size was >3GB. I flushed it and reduced the vaccum size to 500MB and time to 7d. This reduced the boot time. However, I would also want to disable unnecessary services.

Comment: It's _possible_ there will be issues with GDM, if you're using that to log in. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7):

As a general rule, if something is DBus based (and accounts-daemon is), it's safe to turn off automatic startup of it, as it will just get started by DBus whenever something actually needs it.

For this particular case, the `accounts-daemon` is the executable component of the FD.O [AccountsService](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/AccountsService/), which handles non-priveleged listing of account information (because apparently using libc routines for this like you should is too hard for GNOME developers to do).  It may or may not be used by the display manager (login screen), the screensaver, and the account management tools in your desktop environment.  As mentioned above, DBus starts requested services on-demand, so this is something that you can definitely disable automatic startup of, but it probably will be started by other components of your system (especially if you're using GNOME or KDE for your desktop).

Comment: This  is not because "using libc routines is too hard", but because using a dbus service allows separation of privileged activities.

Comment: I'm talking about lookup of account information, not editing accounts.  Even if you're using SELinux, most normal users have to have read access to at least `/etc/passwd`, and core software has to have read access to `/etc/groups`.  Those therefore _are not_ privileged operations, and thus don't require privilege separation.  Similarly, outside of very paranoid configurations, access by regular users is functionally required for any centralized user database.

Comment: Apps like Control Center are the main consumers. I think Shell and GDM use it to get user lists; this is something that's pretty low-level in glibc and makes sense to have in a library. \*shrug*. I'm told the plan is to eventually replace it with SSSD but someone needs to do the work for that.

Comment: getpwent is NOT a privileged activity, and AccountsService is in fact broken because it only considers /etc/passwd instead of entries returned by getpwent (which can be from far more sources than simply /etc/passwd). They could've made a DBUS wrapper on top of getpwent, but instead they decided to make something utterly broken and force it on anyone using GNOME. Not surprising.